# How to implement iterator as an attribute of a class in Java

Tags: java, iterator

let's say I have this simple MyArray class, with two simple methods: add, delete and an iterator. In the main method we can see how it is supposed to be used:

```
public class MyArray {
int start;
int end;
int[] arr;
myIterator it;
public MyArray(){
    this.start=0;
    this.end=0;
    this.arr=new int[500];
    it=new myIterator();
}
public void add(int el){
    this.arr[this.end]=el;
    this.end++;
}
public void delete(){
    this.arr[this.start]=0;
    this.start++;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    MyArray m=new MyArray();

    m.add(3);
    m.add(299);
    m.add(19);
    m.add(27);
    while(m.it.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(m.it.next());
    }
}
```

And then MyIterator should be implemented somehow:

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class myIterator implements Iterator{

@Override
public boolean hasNext() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public Object next() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void remove() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

MyIterator should iterate *arr* from *MyArray* class, from *start* to *end* values; both are also attributes of *MyArray*. So, as *MyIterator* should use *MyArray* attributes, how should MyIterator be implemented?  Perhaps I can send the current object in the initialization:

```
it=new myIterator(this);
```

But I guess it's not the best soultion. Or maybe MyArray itself should implement Iterator interface? How is this solved?

EDIT:

Ok, thanks to everybody. This was a simple example of what I wnat to do, so don't care about fixed length array. Waht I really want to do is a circular FIFO, that's why `start` and `end` are the cursors.

This circular FIFO will be an array of pairs of ints with, e.g., size 300: `int[][] arr=new int[300][2]`.

When iterating a circular array I have to take care if the counter arrives to the end and make it start from the beginning, so this is how I have solved it:

```
if  (this.start >= this.end )   temp_end=this.end+this.buff.length; 
else    temp_end=this.end;
int ii;
int j=0;
int[] value=new int[2];
for(int i=this.start; i<temp_end; i++){
    ii=i% this.arr.length;
    value=this.buff[ii]; 
    //do anything with value
```

}

But I would like to avoid worrying about these things and just iterate in a simple way, I can do this with iterator interface, but then I have 2 problems: the first one I already explained and has been solved by many answers, and the second one is that my array is made of pairs of ints, and I can't use iterator with primitive types.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its very unusual to maintain an iterator as an instance variable of the class.  You can only traverse the array once - probably not what you want. More likely, you want your class to provide an iterator to anyone that wants to traverse your array. A more traditional iterator is below.

Java 5+ code - I haven't tried to compile or run, so it may be contain errors (not near a dev machine right now).  It also uses autobox'ing for converting `Integer` to `int`.

```
public class MyArray implements Iterable<Integer> {

    public static class MyIterator implements Iterator<Integer> {

        private final MyArray myArray;
        private int current;

        MyIterator(MyArray myArray) {
            this.myArray = myArray;
            this.current = myArray.start;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return current < myArray.end;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer next() {
            if (! hasNext())   throw new NoSuchElementException();
            return myArray.arr[current++];
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            // Choose exception or implementation: 
            throw new OperationNotSupportedException();
            // or
            //// if (! hasNext())   throw new NoSuchElementException();
            //// if (currrent + 1 < myArray.end) {
            ////     System.arraycopy(myArray.arr, current+1, myArray.arr, current, myArray.end - current-1);
            //// }
            //// myArray.end--;
        }
    }

    ....

    // Most of the rest of MyArray is the same except adding a new iterator method ....

    public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
        return new MyIterator();
    }

    // The rest of MyArray is the same ....

}
```

---

Also note: be careful of not hitting that 500 element limit on your static array.  Consider using the ArrayList class instead if you can.

Comment: WTF? Why would you implement the iterator as a static class? You're creating unnecessary global scope that could lead to some serious thread-safety issues down the road. Also, by declaring myArray as final you're introducing an unnecessary constraint that makes it impossible to resize the array after it's initially created.

Comment: You suggest using the ArrayList class but at it's core all an ArrayList is, is a List implementation that uses a resizable array internally. With a little work, this class could easily be extended with a resizable array internally. I'd consider downvoting but I'd rather provide a better answer.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion it is better to implement MyArray as common [Iterable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) object, so it can be used in a for statement.

My suggestion:

```
/**
 * My array
 */
public class MyArray<TItem> implements Iterable<TItem>
{
    /**
     * Internal used iterator.
     */
    private class MyArrayIterator<TItem> implements Iterator<TItem>
    {
        private MyArray<TItem> _array;

        /**
         * @param array The underlying array.
         */
        public MyArrayIterator(MyArray<TItem> array)
        {
            this._array = array;
        }

        /**
         * Gets the underlying array.
         * 
         * @return The underlying array.
         */
        public MyArray<TItem> getArray() {
            return this._array;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public TItem next() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }

    public void add(int el){
        // do add
    }

    public void delete(){
        // do delete
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<TItem> iterator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new MyArrayIterator<TItem>(this);
    }
}
```

As I said you can use it in a for statement:

```
private static void test(MyArray<String> strArray)
{
    for (String str: strArray) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: What if my TItem is supposed to be an array of ints, int[], instead of a String? this is primitive type so I can't use it as a parameter

Comment: @de3 you can not implement either Iterator or Iterable with primitive types. Iterator only supports objects.

Answer (score 2):

[Iterator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) is an interface . `Iterator<E>` which means **only Object** can go here (E) . 
`Iterator<Integer>` is legal but `Integer<int>` is not because int is primitive data type

You can change the array to the [ArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and then iterate over this arraylist. I added `getIterator()` method that returns the `arraylist.iterator()` and test it in `main()` method

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class MyArray {
 int start;
 int end;
 ArrayList<Integer> arr;


 public MyArray() {
  this.start = 0;
  this.end = 0;
  arr = new ArrayList<Integer>(500);
 }

 public void add(int el) {
  arr.add(el);
  this.end++;
 }

 public void delete() {
  arr.remove(arr.size()-1);
  this.start++;
 }

 public Iterator<Integer> getIterator(){
  return arr.iterator();
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  MyArray m = new MyArray();

  m.add(3);
  m.add(299);
  m.add(19);
  m.add(27);

  Iterator<Integer> it = m.getIterator();

  while(it.hasNext()){
   System.out.println(it.next());
  }

 }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to let `MyArray` implement the interface `java.lang.Iterable` and create an instance of an iterator per `iterator()` call (as an anonymous class). Then you can use an instance of `MyArray` directly in a `foreach` construct:

```
public class MyArray implements Iterable {

  // ...

  // Only arr is needed now as an instance variable.
  // int start;
  // int end;
  int[] arr;
  // myIterator it;

  /**
   *  From interface Iterable.
   */
  public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {

    return new Iterator<Integer>() {
      // The next array position to return
      int pos = 0;

      public boolean hasNext() {
        return pos < arr.length;
      }

      public Integer next() {
        if(hasNext()) 
          return arr[pos++];
        else
          throw new NoSuchElementException();
      }

      public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
      }
    }
  }


}
```

**Update:** According to BertF's comment I updated my code to make it clear, that the only instance variable for class `MyArray` is now `arr`. The state for the iterator is now inside the anonymous `Iterator` implementation. So you can create multiple iterator instances which don't interfere each other.

Comment: My attention to his instance variables.

Comment: I updated my code to emphasize that there is no need for the original `start`, `end` and `it` instance variables.

Comment: `start` is how he `delete`s and end is how he `add`s. Without them, he'll have to reallocate/resize the array everytime he adds and deletes from it.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: this does not work for arrays of primitive types:
you could use Arrays for this:

`it = new Arrays.asList(arr).subList(start, end).iterator();`
END OF EDIT

If you really want to implement your own iterator, I would suggest an internal class in this scenario. This way you can access MyArray.this from myIterator.

```
public class MyArray {
    ....
    private class myIterator implements Iterator{
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MyArray should implement the Iterator as it is also responsible for maintaining the array. Simple encapsulation principle.