# Cannot convert from Object to <myClass> error and Query about pointers

Tags: java, object, linked-list, converters

Thought I'll first outline the classes I'm working with while constructing a class that holds a doubly-linked list (I'm not using the Java inbuilt class):

```
    class Node { //Forms the nodes of the list
        private Object element;
        private Node next;
        private Node prev;  //....other methods etc.
}

    public class mylist implements Iterable<Node> {
     Node head; Node tail; //....
    @Override
        public Iterator<Node> iterator() {
            return new myit(this);
        }
    public class myit implements Iterator<Node> {       
            mylist set; 
            Node curr;
            myit(mylist input) {
                set=input;
                curr=set.head;
            }
            @Override
                public boolean hasNext() {
                    return (!(curr.getNext()==set.tail));
                }
            @Override
            public Node next() {
                if (this.hasNext()) return curr.getNext();
            }

        }



    public class Myset {
            mylist set;
            //...
public void Delete(Object o) {

        for(Node p: this.set) {
            if(p.getElement().equals(o)) {
            Node q=p.getNext();
            p.getPrev().setNext(q);
            q.setPrev(p);
            break;
        }}
    }
    public static void main(String[] as) {
            Myset m=new Myset();
            for(int i=1; i<5;i++) {
                m.Insert(new Card(i));
            }
            for(Node n: m.set){
                Card x=n.getElement(); //ERROR HERE
                System.out.println(x.number());
            }}
```

To be clear, all the classes here are defined in separate files. Card is a separate class that I've created. I get an error which says Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to Card in the line indicated. How do I overcome this?
Also, as you might have noticed I've overloaded the iterator function to use it for my linked list class using the ways suggested in [How to implement iterator as an attribute of a class in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533636/how-to-implement-iterator-as-an-attribute-of-a-class-in-java). If you notice glitches/have any suggestions I'd be extremely grateful. 
I also had a question related to the Delete method in Myset. I haven't been able to run the code due to the error above yet, but I have my doubts about this. I'm rather new to Java and I'm used to the idea of working with pointers in C. So do p and q serve as 'pointers' to the memory locations of the original nodes in mylist and would this successfully delete the node?

Comment: *"How do I overcome this?"* You learn about [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html). Or you go old-school and cast the value.

Comment: Node<T> .. T element

Comment: Node.getElement() returns Object. You're trying to assign the object returned to a variable of type Card. So the compiler disagrees: it can't be sure that the object is a Card. So you need to cast: `Card x = (Card) n.getElement();`. Your code is awfully indented, and your variable names are horrible, which makes your code very hard to read, even for you. You would have a much better idea of what your own code does if you formatted it correctly and chose good names. Methods start with a lowercase letter. Classes start with an uppercase letter. camelCase is used.

Comment: Thank you very much. That solved the issue. I'm awfully sorry about the formatting, I'd pasted it and converted it to code in fragments and I realize it looks pretty darned disjointed to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comments, one quick and easy solution is to simply cast the return value of `getElement()` to `Card`:

```
Card x = (Card) n.getElement();
```

The compiler doesn't know that you're only storing `Card` objects in the list, since it can hold any subclass of `Object` (or `Object` itself). In your case, you as the programmer have to tell the compiler what you're doing - and if you **are 100% certain** that the list will only contain `Card` objects you can safely cast the return value to `Card`.